# Mac OS X mySQL custom database path (MAMP PRO)

Tags: macos, mamp, mysql

I'm using MAMP (OS-X 10.6.6) and I want to move my mySQL db folder to my dropbox folder.
The MySQL server MAMP runs stores its databases in

```
/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql
```

..and I can't get it to follow symlinks or aliases to the mysql folder.

Is there a way to change the path mySQL uses for storing its databases? On the MAMP forum they say it's not possible, but I imagine there must be some kind of config file for whatever mySQL server it is that MAMP is running that can be changed to specify an alternative location for the used DBs..?

Anyone know how to acheive this? Storing the DB's on dropbox is the last element I need to solve to be able to work on my projects from my different computers.

Comment: Using TextMate I did a multifile search on the strings 'Support/appsolute/MAMP' and 'PRO/db/mysql' in the directories Applications/MAMP - Applications/MAMP PRO - /Library/Application Support/appsolute and ~/Library/Application Support/appsolute , but no matches were found except for in logfiles and dynamically generated tmp files.. so it seems that the path is either stored in a binary format, or it is stiched together somehow in-app.. I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just realized that its just the finder 'alias' type that won't work. creating a proper unix symlink works fine. so doing this solves the problem and keeps the databases on dropbox.

```
ln -s /Users/username/Dropbox/MAMP_db/mysql /Library/Application\ Support/appsolute/MAMP\ PRO/db/mysql
```

Comment: Yeah this is correct.  Its important to *move* your mysql folder to your dropbox first, THEN open up Terminal and create the symlink. I think you get a duplicate warning, but it can get confusing if you dont do it in order!  Cheers @mwb

Comment: Perfect. Just remember to make sure the directory is backed up first!

Answer (score 1):

mwb's method works. Remember, you also need to be be running Apache/MySQL server as user. Those settings are in MAMP PRO (Server -> General)

If you are going to be using dropbox to access the database on another machine, you will need to have identical paths to Dropbox as well.